# I am having dificulties with Plotly Scatter

Tags: python, plotly, scatter

I am trying to plot over the same graph the Candlesticks of EUR/USD and an array of maximum values for the quotation of EUR/USD, which I take from the sequence of M1 timeframe.

The Candlestick is going fine. The real issue is the second plot, the maximums.
My expectation is the plot to be a sequence of horizontal lines in different quotation, similar to the [Donchian Channel indicator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donchian_channel), but it does not happen that way.

```
import plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
from plotly import graph_objs as go
from plotly import tools
from talib import abstract
from pandas.tseries.offsets import BDay

isBusinessDay = BDay().onOffset

SMA = abstract.SMA
SAR = abstract.SAR

df1 = pd.read_csv('.\EURUSD\EURUSD1.csv',names=['date','hour','open','high','low','close','volume'],parse_dates=[['date', 'hour']])
df1.date_hour=pd.to_datetime(df1.date_hour, format='%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S.%f')
df1.set_index(df1.date_hour)

sma5 = SMA(df1, timeperiod=5, price='close')
sma15 = SMA(df1, timeperiod=15, price='close')
sma60 = SMA(df1, timeperiod=60, price='close')
sma89 = SMA(df1, timeperiod=89, price='close')

df1.insert(5, "SMA5", sma5, True) 
df1.insert(5, "SMA15", sma15, True)
df1.insert(5, "SMA60", sma60, True)
df1.insert(5, "SMA89", sma89, True) 

movimento = []
tp = []
sl = []

columns = list(df1)
j=0
top = len(df1)

try:
    for i in range(top):
        j = i+14
        high=df1.loc[i:j,"high"].values
        low=df1.loc[i:j,"low"].values
        localmax = max(high)
        localmin = min(low)

        if df1.loc[j,"close"] > df1.loc[i,"close"]:
            movimento.append(1)
            tp.append(localmax)
            sl.append(localmin)
        elif df1.loc[j,"close"] < df1.loc[i,"close"]:
            movimento.append(-1)
            tp.append(localmin)
            sl.append(localmax)
        else:
            movimento.append(0)
            tp.append(0)
            sl.append(0)            
except KeyError:
    pass

comp = len(movimento)
print('Tamannho do TP: '+ str(len(tp)))
print('Tamannho do SL: '+ str(len(sl)))
print('Tamannho do MOVIMENTO: '+ str(comp))

for i in range(top - comp):
    movimento.insert(0, np.nan)
    tp.insert(0, np.nan)
    sl.insert(0, np.nan)   

df1.insert(5, "ORDER", movimento, True)
del i
del j
del comp
del high
del low
del localmax
del localmin

df1.insert(5, "TP", tp, True) 
df1.insert(5, "SL", sl, True)

df1 = df1.dropna()
df1.set_index(df1['date_hour'])
match_series = pd.to_datetime(df1['date_hour']).map(isBusinessDay)
df1[match_series]  


graphic1MCandle = go.Candlestick(x=df1.index,open=df1['open'],high=df1['high'],low=df1['low'],close=df1['close'],increasing_line_color= 'blue', decreasing_line_color= 'red')
graphicTP = go.Scatter(x=df1.index, y=tp, name='TP', connectgaps=False, line_shape='hv')

fig = tools.make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1, shared_yaxes=True, shared_xaxes=False)
fig.add_trace(graphic1MCandle, 1,1)
fig.add_trace(graphicTP, 1,1)

fig.update_layout(title='EURUSD - M1 - TP @ 15M',
                   xaxis_title='DATE AND TIME',
                   yaxis_title='EURUSD')

py.offline.plot(fig, filename='tutorial.html')
```

The CSV file with the quotations is here -https://github.com/danielfcastro/MLRobotForex/blob/dev/EURUSD/EURUSD1.csv

Summarizing, the difficulties are:

- The scale of the graph is not ok given the amplitude in the Y axis of prices.
- The Scatter is not a set of horizontal lines but segments that come and go back to price at 0.

Can you help me?

Comment: Your file on github is not public

Comment: Public now.  Sorry about that, @JohanC

Comment: @DanielFerreiraCastro If you're still working on this, would you share a screenshot of the resulting figure?